# How accurate are the laws in Theodore Boone?

Tags: john-grisham, theodore-boone

In *Theodore Boone*, John Grisham mentions several laws, such as about putting flyers on poles, drunk driving, and other random laws. How accurate are these? Are real laws, anywhere?

Examples:

> Theo pressed on, "The law clearly states that permits must be approved for posters and flyers dealing with politicians and people who are running for office, but not for anything else. These flyers are legal as long as they are taken down within ten days. That's the law."
>
> <sub>*The Abduction*, chapter 4</sub>

...

> "What was his BAC?"
>   "What?"
>   "His blood alcohol content."
>   "Oh, that. Does point zero nine sound right?"
>   "Yes. The limit is point zero eight, so he's in trouble. First offense?"
>   "Why heavens yes, Theo...
>   ...
>   "Some of the cops like to scare people. Your brother will not get ten days. He'll pay a fine of six hundred dollars, lose his license for six months, go to driving school, and a year from now his record can be expunged. Did he spend the entire night in jail?"
>   "Yes. I can't imagine..."
>   "Then there's no more jail time...
>
> <sub>*Kid Lawyer*, chapter 22</sub>

Comment: Please be more specific; which laws are you talking about specifically?

Comment: "*drunk driving and other random laws*" - I would say the law against drunk driving is pretty universal and sensible, actually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the laws discussed in the *Theodore Boone* books, such as drunk driving or putting flyers on poles are handled on the local level and therefore the laws will vary. However, in many jurisdictions there are laws for such things. The laws for posting signs will generally be set at the state, county, and municipal levels. The best example is putting signs on posts, which in most states is legal for a certain length of time and after that length of time it must be permitted, which fits with the description of the law in *Theodore Boone*.

Answer (score 3):

Since you only mention 2 laws in your question (at the time of writing this answer), I'll address those 2 laws.

> Drunk driving is often referred to as driving under the influence of
>   alcohol, or DUI, but can also be known as as driving while
>   intoxicated, or DWI, or by similar terms. Regardless of the language
>   used, it is a crime in every state, and one that often comes with
>   significant penalties.  -- [source](http://www.criminaldefenselawyer.com/crime-penalties/federal/Felony-DUI.htm)

For posting flyers on telephone poles in New York City:

> It is illegal for any person to paste, post, paint, print, nail, or attach or affix by any means whatsoever any handbill, poster, notice, sign, advertisement, sticker, or other printed material upon any curb, gutter, flagstone, tree, lamppost, awning post, telegraph pole, telephone pole, public utility pole, public garbage bin, bus shelter, bridge, elevated train structure, highway fence, barrel, box, parking meter, mailbox, traffic control device, traffic stanchion, traffic sign (including pole), tree box, tree pit protection device, bench, traffic barrier, city-owned grassy area adjacent to a street, hydrant, or other similar public item on any street. -- [source](http://www1.nyc.gov/assets/dsny/about/laws/posting-and-graffiti-laws.shtml)

Further addressing your quote,

> It is illegal for any person to affix or attach any sticker or decal on a public or private building or structure. There is a rebuttable presumption that the person whose name, telephone number, or any other identifying information appears on any sticker or decal is in violation. Every sticker or decal shall be deemed a separate violation. Anyone found to have violated this provision, in addition to any penalty imposed, shall also be responsible for the cost of the removal of the unauthorized sticker or decal.

I used New York City as an example, but these regulations really just vary from place to place.